# List of all windows server names from parameter store

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I have this parameter and it works as expected.

```
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: /aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2016-English-Core-Containers
```

But how do I get the list of all windows servers? The following command does not return anything.

> aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest" --region us-east-1

Comment: That command works very nicely for me!

Comment: The "put parameter" command works as expected. I can check the new paramter from console. But get-parameter does not return anything. strange!

aws ssm put-parameter --name myEC2TypeDev1 --type String --value "t2.small"

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can you copy-paste the list of windows server names as answer?

Comment: This was related to restricted permissions granted to IAM user !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command works fine for me, returning 23 AMIs:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest" --region us-east-1
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2008-R2_SP1-English-64Bit-SQL_2012_SP4_Express",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "ami-0a2e90df8bb31df6f",
            "Version": 29,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1576555239.669,
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2008-R2_SP1-English-64Bit-SQL_2012_SP4_Express"
        },
        {
            "Name": "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-Chinese_Simplified-64Bit-Base",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "ami-0bedade339716cc2b",
            "Version": 48,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1576555364.453,
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-Chinese_Simplified-64Bit-Base"
        },
        ...
```

I'm using a Mac. If you are using Windows, you might need to fiddle with the quotation marks (or even remove them).

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on Windows as well.

[image]